# How to use placeholder for "date" in iPhone and Android mobiles

Tags: android, iphone, html

I'm trying to get a placeholder for date field in a mobile website. 
But it shows as empty textbox.

I used to following code te the placeholder, is there an other way to do it?

```
<li><input type="date" name="" value="" placeholder="Date of Birth"/></li>
```